# Generic issue on kotlin

Tags: spring-boot, generics, kotlin, resttemplate

I'm trying to implement a basic function for handling external API calls :

```
   inline fun <reified T> get(url: String): T? {

        try {

            val restTemplate = RestTemplate()
            val response = restTemplate.exchange<Any>(
                url,
                HttpMethod.GET,
                headersForRestTemplate,
                T::class)

            return response.getBody() as T

        } catch (e: Exception) {
            log.info("Exception ::" + e.message)
            throw ServiceException(e)
        }

    }
```

The way I'm calling it is pretty straightforward :

```
 api.get<SWObject>(Utils.SW_API)
```

When trying to execute that code, I get a cast exception :

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to jp.co.xx.demo.models.SWObject
```

Object returned is not an instance of the `SWObject` class but a `LinkedHashMap`. I'm still struggling with `reified` or `inline` keyword, sorry if my implementation doesn't follow the best practices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `T::class.java` instead of `T::class` in the `exchange` method and remove the explicit type argument `Any` from the `exchange` method invocation as it became unnecessary. You also don't need to cast the response body to `T`.

```
inline fun <reified T> get(url: String): T? {
    try {
        val restTemplate = RestTemplate()
        val response = restTemplate.exchange(
            url,
            HttpMethod.GET,
            headersForRestTemplate,
            T::class.java
        )

        return response.getBody()
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        log.info("Exception ::" + e.message)
        throw ServiceException(e)
    }
}
```

`Object::class` returns a Kotlin class (`KClass`) while `Object::class.java` returns a Java class (`Class`) and is equivalent to Java's `Object.class`. Note that `KClass` is not the same as `Class`.

The `exchange` method just expects its `responseType` argument to be the type of `Class` (or `ParametrizedTypeReference` but that's not the case for that).

Comment: perfect answer, beyond my expectations ~ Thanks also for the cast tips !

Comment: For me still facing same issue, data getting correct but instead type T giving LinkedHashMap object. Please could you help on this?